# Problem 3-33 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak. What is $g$? I cannot understand the author's intention for this problem at all.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Problem 3-33.
> If $f:[a,b]\times [c,d]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $D_2f$ is continuous, define $F(x,y)=\int_a^x f(t,y)dt$.
> (a) Find $D_1F$ and $D_2F$.
> (b) If $G(x)=\int_a^{g(x)} f(t,x)dt$, find $G'(x)$.

I solved (a) as follows:

$D_1F(x,y)=f(x,y)$ by a famous theorem in one variable calculus.
$D_2F(x,y)=\int_a^x D_2f(t,y)dt$ by [Problem 3-32](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4822026/1226161).

But I could not solve (b).

At first, what is $g$?
I guess $g$ is a function from $[c,d]$ to $[a,b]$ and $g$ is differentiable on $[c,d]$.
$G(x)=F(g(x),x)$.
$G'(x)=D_1F(g(x),x)\cdot g'(x)+D_2F(g(x),x)=f(g(x),x)\cdot g'(x)+\int_a^{g(x)} D_2f(t,x)dt$.

I cannot understand the author's intention for this problem at all.

Comment: The goal of this problem was most likely just to have you see that when both the bound and the integrand depend on $x$, then the trick is to create a two-variable function $(x,y) \mapsto F(x,y)$ which will allow you to transform the original differentiation problem into a simpler "partial differentiation along each variable" problem.

Comment: @BrunoB thank you very much for your answer.